# await in simple for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have to generate n signatures. For that I must invoke a promise n number of times. Do I have to use Promise.all? Is there another way?

```
const response = [];
for( let i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
    response.push(await generateSignature())
}
```

this gives me an eslint issue no-await-in-loop.

Comment: If you need to make requests in serial, your current code is perfectly fine. If you 're able to make the requests in parallel, better to use `Promise.all`.

Comment: The no-await-in-loop rule is pretty pointless as you *want* to do stuff in sequence occasionally.